# Count wins, games and type of game in array of objects and create object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am sure there is already an answer as well as an "easy" solution to this, but I did not find something in the last hour.

So I have this object:

```js
[
  {
    "win": false,
    "switched": false
  },
  {
    "win": false,
    "switched": false
  },
  {
    "win": true,
    "switched": true
  },
  {
    "win": true,
    "switched": true
  }
]
```

which is showing the results of four monty-hall games. I want to create an object from this    array that would have the following structure:

```js
{
    switched: {
        played: 2,
        won: 2
    },
    put: {
        played: 2,
        lost: 2
    }
}
```

So actually if the object in the upper array has `switched: true` I want to increase the value of `switched["played"]`by 1 and it has also `won: true` I want to increase the value of the keys `switched["won"]` also by one. Vice versa for `switched: false` I wand to put everything in the results-object under the key `put`.

I tried some rather embarrassing approaches with `reduce`, but I think there must be an "easier" way (mine did not work at all...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const items = [{
    win: false,
    switched: false
  },
  {
    win: false,
    switched: false
  },
  {
    win: true,
    switched: true
  },
  {
    win: true,
    switched: true
  }
];

const res = items.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => {
    // If your current item is switched
    return cur["switched"]
      ? { // ... deal with the switched part, leave the rest as is
          ...acc,
          switched: {
            played: acc.switched.played + 1, // increase the played counter by 1, based on whatever your accumulator currently has
            won: acc.switched.won + Number(cur.win) // cast your win property to number (true -> 1, false -> 0) and increase accordngily
          }
        }
      : { // ... otherwise deal with the put part, leave the rest as is
          ...acc,
          put: {
            played: acc.put.played + 1,
            lost: acc.put.lost + Number(!cur.win) // negate your win so that it reflects a loss, cast to number and increase accordingly
          }
        };
  },
  // Initialize your accumulator
  {
    switched: {
      played: 0,
      won: 0
    },
    put: {
      played: 0,
      lost: 0
    }
  }
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: easier to put a snippet here

Comment: Just one question: Why does it make a difference if I put `played: acc.switched.played + 1,` or `played: acc.switched.played++` ? Because with the latter it did not work for some reason

Comment: @Lenn Consider the following example: `let m = 0; let n = m++`. What would the be the `n`'s value ? Answer is 0, not 1. It has to do with operator precedence in js and other languages in general. Moreover, calling the `++` operator you are actually mutating the `acc.switched` object which the proposed solution avoids.

Comment: @Lenn the `++` would work fine for the other answer proposed by @A1exandr Belan since it is mutating the  `acc` object

Comment: thanks a lot!! I really appreciate it:) I still did not get completely why your solution is not modifying the `acc` object. I think I yet did not grasp entirely how the Object spreading works and what it is doing in this case. 
In any case: Thank you very much!:)

Comment: @Nikkkshit the snippet is not correctly working

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help you

```js
const data = [{"win": false,"switched": false},{"win": false,"switched": false},{"win": true,"switched": true},{"win": true,"switched": true}];

const initScores = {
    switched: {
        played: 0,
        won: 0,
    },
    put: {
        played: 0,
        lost: 0,
    }
};

const result = data.reduce((acc, {win, switched})=> {
    if (switched) {
        acc.switched.played += 1;
        acc.switched.won += win ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        acc.put.played += 1;
        acc.put.lost += !win ? 1 : 0;
    }
    return acc;
}, initScores);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Could you please add explanation for your code?

Answer (score 0):

With [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can supply the logic based on the accumulated object `acc` and the current game `curr`.

In the case that `curr` had been switched, you must assign the `switched` property to `acc`. However, it may be `undefined`, so you should assign it to a default object if this happens.

The same login applies to the other part of the problem. Regarding `put` property, just replace all those `switched` with `put` and `won` by `lost`.

```js
const obj=[{win:false,switched:false},{win:false,switched:false},{win:true,switched:true},{win:true,switched:true}]

const output = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.switched ?
    (acc.switched = (
        {
            won: curr.win ? acc.switched.won + 1 : acc.switched.won,
            played: acc.switched.played + 1
        }
    ), acc) :
    (acc.put = (
        {
            lost: !curr.win ? acc.put.lost + 1 : acc.put.lost,
            played: acc.put.played + 1
        }
    ), acc),
    {
        switched: {
            won: 0,
            played: 0
        },
        put: {
            lost: 0,
            played: 0
        }
    })

console.log(output)
```